# Using a variable column name in a rails helper method where( ) query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with a User model that includes booleans for 6 days

```
[sun20, mon21, tue22, wed23, thur24, fri25]
```

with each user having option to confirm which of the 6 days they are participating in.

I'm trying to define a simple helper method:

```
  def day_confirmed(day)
    User.where(day: true).count
  end
```

where I could pass in a day and find out how many users are confirmed for that day, like so:

```
day_confirmed('mon21')
```

My problem is that when I use `day` in the `where()`, rails assumes that I'm searching for a column named `day` instead of outputting the value that I'm passing in to my method.

Surely I'm forgetting something, right?

Comment: In detail of your search. You are try to find users which have column_name 'mon21' set as true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax:

```
User.where( day: true )
```

Is equivalent to:

```
User.where( :day => true )
```

That's because using `:` in a hash instead of `=>`, e.g. `{ foo: bar }`, is the same as using a symbol for the key, e.g. `{ :foo => bar }`. Perhaps this will help:

```
foo = "I am a key"

hsh = { foo: "bar" }
# => { :foo => "bar" }

hsh.keys
# => [ :foo ]

hsh = { foo => "bar" }
# => { "I am a key" => "bar" }

hsh.keys
# => [ "I am a key" ]
```

So, if you want to use the value of the variable `day` rather than the symbol `:day` as the key, try this instead:

```
User.where( day => true )
```

Answer (score 2):

If these are your column names, `[sun20, mon21, tue22, wed23, thur24, fri25]`

And you are calling `day_confirmed('mon21')` and trying to find the column 'mon21' where it is `true`, you can use `.to_sym` on the `date` variable

```
 def day_confirmed(day)
    User.where(day.to_sym => true).count
  end
```

the `.to_sym` will get the value of `date`, and covert it to `:mon21`